# Structuring an input file

Tags: code-formatting, io

I am in the process of structuring a small program to perform some hydraulic analysis of pipe flow. As I am envisioning this, the program will read an input file, store the input parameters in a suitable way, operate on them and finally output results. I am struggling with how to structure the input file in a sane way; that is, in a way that a human can write it easily and a machine can parse it easily. A sample input file made available to me for a similar program is just a stream of comma-separated numbers that don't make much sense on their own, so that's the scenario I am trying to avoid.

Though I am giving the details of my particular problem, I am more interested in general input-file structuring strategies. Is a stream of comma-separated values my best bet? Would I be better off using some sort of key:value structure? I don't know much about this, so any help will probably put me in a better track than I am now.

Comment: For your specific problem, you could use a GUI using something like .NET or Swing also you could use Excel. Having captured data in the GUI, you can validate it and commit it to either a file or a database. It may be useful to group inputs in a database rather than in files. However, this is not always the case.

Comment: A GUI would be ideal and something I thought about doing and that I will definitely do after I submit the project. It's a hydraulics class, not a programming class, so the UI is an afterthought. Having a sane input file is already considered overkill. I would like to extend this past the project submission requirements, so spending time on the input makes sense to me. Could you elaborate a bit on the database vs. file input grouping issue you raise? A quick search didn't give me any hints.

Comment: Your generally want to store data is a safe storage that can be queried with ease and can have its data protected from tampering as much as possible. Regular text files on a pc are generally not protected (unless placed in secure folders) and they can be tampered with (say by removing a comma or a quote) which may result the program to fail. Also, regular files don't offer flexible querying other than text search and Excel filtering. A database may be an overkil for your project but may be a good suggestion for a serious product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [YAML](http://yaml.org/start.html). It is a data serialization language that is designed to be human readable. Here's a sample from the link:

```
--- !clarkevans.com/^invoice
invoice: 34843
date   : 2001-01-23
bill-to: &id001
    given  : Chris
    family : Dumars
    address:
        lines: |
            458 Walkman Dr.
            Suite #292
        city    : Royal Oak
        state   : MI
        postal  : 48046
```

There are [parsers available](http://yaml.org) for all mainstream languages.

Comment: Thanks you for pointing me in this direction. This looks like something I could use for this project. I'll come back and mark this answer as the answer in a while. Hopefully others will chime in with more ideas.

Answer (score 4):

> I am struggling with how to structure the input file in a sane way; that is, in a way that a human can write it easily and a machine can parse it easily.

It greatly depends on the complexity and the quantity of information you need to input.  By complexity, I mean the relations between pieces fragments of information: a time series reporting the results of a measure at different time points has virtually no complexity, even if it is megabytes big, while describing the allocation of rooms and times to lectures in a university has a larger complexity, because there is a lot of constraints (only one lecture at a time in a given room, a professor cannot lecture simultaneously at several places, and so on).

Think to all that you want to do with the input of your program:

1. *Prepare the input.* obviously the input has to be prepared.  It is easier if the input format follows an organisation similar to the output format of the methodology (not necessarily a computer program) used to prepare the data.  Then, it is easy to resume from an interruption when preparing the input.
2. *Review the input.* if your program delivers questionable results, you will want to review the input.  It is then important that the format used be clear and put relevant information to the front.  (Complex data will probably require an exploration program to be succesfully reviewed, anyway.)
3. *Correct the input.* Once you spot a flaw, you want to correct it.  If your data is complex, a fix will not be limited to a specific location of the file but will have repercussions in other places.  Also, the fix could need to be peer-reviewed or checked-in a version control system.
4. *Canonise the input.* If your data is complex, there may be several very different ways to input the data, and you may need to be able to change from one to the other or to answer the simple but hard question: do these two input files represent the same data?

If you have little data, up to two or three screens of text, a key-value format like JSON, YAML or Property lists can be well suited.  Besides having a free imlementation for your favourite language, some also have visual editors (for instance the Property List Editor in Mac OS X can edit property lists, similar programs exist for JSON and probably others). Now, if the data set is small enough, 1. 2. 3. and 4. will remain practicable event if the representation is clumsy.

Now consider the case of a complex data: depending on the value that 1., 2., 3. and 4. for you, you may want to design a small declarative language to represent it.  This can be a very complex task, for which you can use `lex/yacc` or their avatars in your favourite programming language.

If you cannot afford to devise a specialised language, you may rely on SGML/XML that can catch some structure of your data.  An interesting alternative can be to use a simple dictionary format and write an auxiliary program to prepare the input of your main program.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/) files for this, also with an [xml schema](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/) you set the allowed structure of the input file. This would ensure that everyone creating input files used the exact same format (humans are humans), also more importantly ensures that the program parsing the input file gets exactly what it expects

XML parsing is supporting by all programming languages, is efficient, and is easily read by humans.

Comment: what are the benefits of XML if his data is not hierarchical?  i.e. if all can fit in a simple 2D table format, why not put it in a flat file, delimited with something (comma, tab, etc)

Answer (score 1):

*I recommend JSON, but here are three good options,*

XML - eXtended Markup Language - used on the web, SOAP, preferred by Java programmers everywhere, can be validated, transformed, etc.  data elements are tagged using ... open/close tags, and tags can have attributes.  but considered wordy/verbose by many.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_examples.asp

JSON - JavasScript Object Notation - basically 'almost' a javascript object.  data elements are (usually) tagged with names, the open/close tags are simple braces

http://json.org/example.html

YAML - yet another markup language, and shares commonality with JSON.  Often expressed as multiple line records

http://www.yaml.org/start.html

CSV or DSV - Comma (or Delimiter) separated value file - you already have, and find it inadequate.  But extremely popular.